# How to increase the gap between two points in x-axis

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

[image]

I have a graph which looks like above and the code to generate it is

```
ggplot(time_stamp, aes(x=TimeZ,y=Freq,group=1)) + geom_line() + 
geom_point(colour = 'red', size = 4) +
ylab("Freq of Viewers") +
theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(colour="grey20",size=12,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
axis.text.y =  element_text(colour="grey20",size=12,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain")) + 
ggtitle("Time vs Freq of Viewers")
```

Now I want to increase the gap between two points in the x-axis. ie. to increase the gap between T00 and T01 or T15 and T16 so that it looks beautiful.

Comment: You can't just widen the viewing area?  If you increased the gap you might lose some right-side data points.

Comment: Is there no other way??? the graph looks very clumsy.

Comment: I would take off the "T" from each axis label, for one.  That would make it look less cluttered.

Comment: You may check the `breaks` argument [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html)

Comment: Just tilt the labels 90°. `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))`.